# Configure TFS-Azure deployment to use "Release" for build

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, configuration-management, azure-deployment

I'm checking in projects to TFS, to be deployed to the Azure host.

I want the project(s) to be built and deployed as "Release", not "Debug".

I put this code in my `Application_Start`:

```
#if DEBUG 
      throw new System.Exception("An Exception!");
#endif
```

And the exception is thrown, how do I set the TFS builds to be 'Release'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select Items To Build in your build definition you can specify the configuration(s) you want built.

[image: Configs To Build]

Comment: NOTE - you should also make sure you turn off debug compilation in your web.config in your web.Release.config transform: <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />